# Get current Id order and post in php

Tags: php, html, list, post

I have a ul list

```
<ul id="new_fields">
   <li id="id_1" class="ui-state-default">list 1</li>
   <li id="id_7" class="ui-state-default">list 2</li>
   <li id="id_4" class="ui-state-default">list 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the current order of id's and post for example this would post id_1, id_7 and id_4.

Is there a simple way in php to get this oredr and post to a url ?

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML, create an array of the IDs, and post them.

Comment: Thanks I think i get you, ill try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to get the ids and an Ajax call to post it to a url.

```
lists = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-state-default');
x = []
for (var i=0, im=lists.length; im>i; i++) {
  x[i] = lists[i].id;
}
// Here x will be ['id_1','id_7','id_4']
```

Then use ajax to post this to the URL.

```
var url = "your_url_here.php";
var params = "array=" + x.toString();
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```